# How do you access a function stored as an element in a list in R?

Tags: r, list, function

I am using an R package with a function that returns a large nlsList, which is a list of length 10. Each of those 10 list elements are themselves lists of length 5, which includes a list of length 16. This third-level list of length of 16 is a list of functions. I assume they are run-able functions, so my question is: how do I execute them?

For example, if I access the element by name, this is what I get:

```
> tnr.fitL[["2016:CT"]][["m"]]["fitted"]
$fitted
function () 
form
<bytecode: 0x0000000020cb5548>
<environment: 0x0000000020cbade0>
```

This looks like (scant) information about the function, but what I want to do is run the embedded "fitted" function itself, which I would expect to give me the estimated values from a model fit to some data, for which this nlsList object is the output.

If it's of interest, what is generating the nlsList object is the nlsLMList function of the nlraa package, version 0.73.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `tnr.fitL[["2016:CT"]][["m"]][["fitted"]]()` work? (Note the extra brackets and parenthesis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out that you call the embedded functions with the nlsList object as the argument. So for example, for the "fitted" formula, it is called as:

```
> fitted(tnr.fitL)
  2016:CT   2016:CT   2016:CT   2016:CT   2016:CT   2016:CT   2016:CT   2016:CT   2016:CT 
 4.320019  4.320019  9.629277  9.629277  9.629277  9.629277 12.464655 12.464655 12.464655
```

This appears to be the standard "fitted" function in R (in {stats}), called with a model-fit object for which fitted values are relevant (nlsList object, in this case).

So I'm guessing that this is standard functionality for how embedded functions in a List object are to be executed. In this case, I don't believe that the 16 embedded functions (including "fitted") are custom functions to the object, but rather serve as an index and activation point for what standard R functions can be run on the object. Just a guess. If anyone reading this knows where the documentation for how this functionality works in R, please post it. I couldn't find any.

Comment: `fitted()` has different S3 methods for objects of different types. `tnr.fitL` is an `nlsList` object, which also has class `lmList`. You are getting the results of the S3 method `nlme:::fitted.lmList`. It has nothing to do with list objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `()` to perform a function call. i.e. `tnr.fitL[["2016:CT"]][["m"]]["fitted"]()`

Comment: I don't see () in your example. Do you mean this: tnr.fitL[["2016:CT"]][["m"]]["fitted()"]. When I run that, the output is $<NA>
NULL.

Comment: Actually, when I run that, every function in the list returns the same thing: $<NA> NULL.

Comment: OK, yeah, I had tried tnr.fitL[["2016:CT"]][["m"]]["fitted"](). But I get Error: attempt to apply non-function

Comment: Thanks for your time anyway.